# Need help to make a CLS document and I need a \fancyhead with picture and text tabular?

Tags: fancyhdr, includegraphics, mwcls

I'm doing a cls document to be a template.

I'm doing the header with this code, but I can't manage to make the picture to be aligned with the text. I only aligns with the first line in this case the journal name, can anyone help me I need the picture to be in the left before the text and the all the 3 lines of the text should be in front of the picture.

Thanks in advance

```
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset{1cm}
\fancyfootoffset{1cm}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{./images/imageinicio}% Image
        \fontsize{8}{8} \selectfont
        Journal on Teaching Engineering, 1:1 (2015) 5-15 \\
        ISSN XXX-XXXX \\
        DOI: \href{https://doi.org/10.24840/2183-6493\_00X.00X\_00XX}{10.24840/2183-6493\_001.001\_0011}}
        \fancyhead[R]{
        \fontsize{8}{8} \selectfont
        Received: XX December, XXX \\
        Revised: XX December, XXX \\
        Published: XX December, XXXX}
    \fancyfoot[R]{
        \fontsize{8}{8} \selectfont
        \textbf{\thepage}}}
```

Comment: What do you mean "in front of the picture"? Should the text be printed on top of the picture, thereby obscuring the picture a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve? By the way, I think `\fontsize{8}{9}` is nicer, or maybe even `\fontsize{8}{10}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[headheight=45pt, includehead]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset{1cm}
\fancyfootoffset{1cm}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
      \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image}
    \end{tabular}
    \fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
      Journal on Teaching Engineering, 1:1 (2015) 5-15 \\
      ISSN XXX-XXXX \\
      DOI: \href{https://doi.org/10.24840/2183-6493\_00X.00X\_00XX}{10.24840/2183-6493\_001.001\_0011}
    \end{tabular}}
    
  \fancyhead[R]{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}
      Received: XX December, XXX \\
      Revised: XX December, XXX \\
      Published: XX December, XXXX
    \end{tabular}}
  \fancyfoot[R]{
    \fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont
    \textbf{\thepage}}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\kant[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tks. Worked so well, real nice coding :) tks.